# fill sidebar form from sheet

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In google sheet, I want to fill a form in a sidebar with values from the active sheet. Since I can't use a click on cell trigger, i want to use a function that takes the value of the active cell when a button in the sidebar is clicked. 
I wrote this code but it didn't work unfortunately,

I am new to Apps script so excuse my low level code :)
Thank you !

test_sidebar.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
   <script>

 function tSubmit(form){

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateT).getT(form);
 }

 function updateT(cellValue){
 var div=document.getEelementById('T');
 div.innerHTML='<input name="T" size = 10 value=' + cellValue + '>K'
 }

   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
    <font color="red">Select conditions of interest:</font><p>
<ul><input value=T type="Button" onClick="tSubmit(this)"><div id="T"> = <input name="T" size = 10>K</div></ul>
<ul><i>P</i> = <input name="P" size = 10>bar</ul>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

code.gs :

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test_sidebar')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}

  function getT(form){
   var cellValue= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
  return cellValue;
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in the html file.  Remove the extra e in getElementByID to make it:

```
var div=document.getElementById('T');
```

Also, there is no need to try to pass the form, which is also causing a problem anyway, so just remove those portions.  You final codes will be:

test_sidebar.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
   <script>

 function tSubmit(){

      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateT).getT();
 }

 function updateT(cellValue){
 var div=document.getElementById('T');
 div.innerHTML='<input name="T" size = 10 value=' + cellValue + '>K'
 }

   </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
    <font color="red">Select conditions of interest:</font><p>
<ul><input value=T type="Button" onClick="tSubmit()"><div id="T"> = <input name="T" size = 10>K</div></ul>
<ul><i>P</i> = <input name="P" size = 10>bar</ul>
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

code.gs :

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
      .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test_sidebar')
      .setTitle('My custom sidebar')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}

function getT(){
  var cellValue= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getValue();
  return cellValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Btw you can trigger a function with the use of an Image, and linking that image to a function.. A "trick" to trigger something from the cell